# GRUB dual boot windows linux - device recognition problem

Tags: ubuntu, grub, bios

I'm using GRUB to dual boot Linux(Ubuntu) + Windows(7).

After booting into Linux, the next time I boot Windows, I am not able to use my mouse or keyboard inside the operating system.

The only thing I found that fixes this is going into my BIOS and then selecting "Save and reboot". I suspect this is a clue because I change no BIOS settings.

Is my BIOS overwriting a setting changed by GRUB?

I would appreciate any insights. I been trying to solve this problem on my own for a while without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRUB does not really have any USB-specific functionality: it relies on the system firmware to provide a keyboard interface, and does not use the mouse at all.

Does your computer have USB3.x? If so, have you installed the USB3 drivers to Windows 7? If not, it might be that the BIOS initially sets the system to a mode that allows USB2 controllers to provide legacy compatibility (so Windows 7 can use the devices with USB2 drivers), but when you boot Linux, it switches the hardware to fully native USB3 mode which cannot be understood by Windows 7 without add-on drivers. For some reason this mode does not get reset at boot unless you visit the BIOS settings.

(The first systems with USB3 had it as an add-on controller, then there were some chipsets whose USB ports were switchable between USB2/USB3 controllers for legacy OS compatibility, and finally new systems only have a USB3 controllers. Knowing where your system is in this USB3 continuum would be very helpful.)
You might want to tell more about your hardware, especially about the system's USB controllers and Windows USB controller drivers.